# bootstrap's glyphicon does not manifest itself

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried glyphicon example from official tutorial,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

However, it did not work as intended,

[image]

I have linked bootstrap with version 3.3.7

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'article/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />`

I locate the problem

the code in bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: href looks wrong.

Comment: Is your static files being loaded correctly? inspect in browser.
Check if static tag is loaded in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you didn't include the required `fonts` to use glyphicon. If you do not want to add those font, then simply add `cdn` link of bootstrap css like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

Hope this will help you.